# How to compare text files and delete duplicates (Linux terminal commands)

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

Suppose I have two directories named **dir_one** and **dir_two**. In each of these directories I have a text file named **data.txt**. In other words, there are two files in two separate directories: **/dir_one/data.txt** and **/dir_one/data.txt** Despite the similar file-names, the two text files may or may not have the same contents!

What I am trying to do is this:

1. Compare the contents of the text files: ./dir_one/data.txt and ./dir_one/data.txt
2. If the contents are identical, delete one of the text files.

I have entered the following at the command terminal:

```
diff -qrs ./dir_one/data.txt ./dir_two/data.txt
```

and I receive the following message:

```
Files ./dir_one/data.txt ./dir_two/data.txt are identical.
```

Now that I know that the two text files are identical, I can use the `rm` command to remove one of them. So far, so good. However...

The problem is that *I want to automate the deletion process*. I do not want to have to enter the `rm` at the command line. Is there any possible way to do this - in a script, for example?

I would also like to know how to compare a large set of text files in one directory against a large set of text files in another directory. Again, for any files found to be identical, one of the duplicates should be deleted. Is this possible too?

I've found similar questions, but none about automating the deletion of the one of the duplicate files. Note that I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need fdupes.

```
fdupes -r /some/directory/path > /some/directory/path/fdupes.log
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, @UberDoyle. This is quite useful information. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` returns exit status 0 if the files are the same, 1 if they're different, and 2 if there is an error.  You can use that to decide to execute the rm command

```
diff file1 file2 && rm file2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jim Garrison. This looks like what I'm after. Could you tell me if this would work in the situation of recursively comparing files in subdirectories, i.e. when specifying the option: -r? Cheers.

Comment: You would need to run each comparison in its own process.  I suspect if you run it with `-r` the result will be zero if _all_ the files are equal, and non-zero if any are different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I initially wrote some time ago and polished recently.  You should run it from the directory you want to deduplicate.  It will place all duplicates in a directory outside of the "cleaned" directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script walks through all files in the current directory,
# checks if there are duplicates (it compares only files with
# the same size) and moves duplicates to $duplicates_dir.
#
# options:
# -H  remove hidden files (and files in hidden folders)
# -n  dry-run: show duplicates, but don't remove them
# -z  deduplicate empty files as well

while getopts "Hnz" opts; do
    case $opts in
    H)
        remove_hidden="yes";;
    n)
        dry_run="yes";;
    z)
        remove_empty="yes";;
    esac
done

# support filenames with spaces:
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

working_dir="$PWD"
working_dir_name=$(echo $working_dir | sed 's|.*/||')

# prepare some temp directories:
filelist_dir="$working_dir/../$working_dir_name-filelist/"
duplicates_dir="$working_dir/../$working_dir_name-duplicates/"
if [[ -d $filelist_dir || -d $duplicates_dir ]]; then
    echo "ERROR! Directories:"
    echo "  $filelist_dir"
    echo "and/or"
    echo "  $duplicates_dir"
    echo "already exist!  Aborting."
    exit 1
fi
mkdir $filelist_dir
mkdir $duplicates_dir

# get information about files:
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%s %n" | \
     sort -nr > $filelist_dir/filelist.txt

if [[ "$remove_hidden" != "yes" ]]; then
    grep -v "/\." $filelist_dir/filelist.txt > $filelist_dir/no-hidden.txt
    mv $filelist_dir/no-hidden.txt $filelist_dir/filelist.txt
fi

echo "$(cat $filelist_dir/filelist.txt | wc -l)" \
     "files to compare in directory $working_dir"
echo "Creating file list..."

# divide the list of files into sublists with files of the same size
while read string; do
    number=$(echo $string | sed 's/\..*$//' | sed 's/ //')
    filename=$(echo $string | sed 's/.[^.]*\./\./')
    echo $filename >> $filelist_dir/size-$number.txt
done < "$filelist_dir/filelist.txt"

# plough through the files
for filesize in $(find $filelist_dir -type f | grep "size-"); do
    if [[ -z $remove_empty && $filesize == *"size-0.txt" ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    filecount=$(cat $filesize | wc -l)
    # there are more than 1 file of particular size ->
    # these may be duplicates
    if [ $filecount -gt 1 ]; then
        if [ $filecount -gt 200 ]; then
            echo ""
            echo "Warning: more than 200 files with filesize" \
                 $(echo $filesize | sed 's|.*/||' | \
                 sed 's/size-//' | sed 's/\.txt//') \
                 "bytes."
            echo "Since every file needs to be compared with"
            echo "every other file, this may take a long time."
        fi

        for fileA in $(cat $filesize); do
            if [ -f "$fileA" ]; then
                for fileB in $(cat $filesize); do
                    if [ -f "$fileB" ] && [ "$fileB" != "$fileA" ]; then
                        # diff will exit with 0 iff files are the same.
                        diff -q "$fileA" "$fileB" 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
                        if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
                            # detect if one filename is a substring of another
                            # so that in case of foo.txt and foo(copy).txt
                            # the script will remove foo(copy).txt
                            # supports filenames with no extension.

                            fileA_name=$(echo $fileA | sed 's|.*/||')
                            fileB_name=$(echo $fileB | sed 's|.*/||')
                            fileA_ext=$(echo $fileA_name | sed 's/.[^.]*//' | sed 's/.*\./\./')
                            fileB_ext=$(echo $fileB_name | sed 's/.[^.]*//' | sed 's/.*\./\./')
                            fileA_name="${fileA_name%%$fileA_ext}"
                            fileB_name="${fileB_name%%$fileB_ext}"

                            if [[ $fileB_name == *$fileA_name* ]]; then
                                echo "  $(echo $fileB | sed 's|\./||')" \
                                    "is a duplicate of" \
                                    "$(echo $fileA | sed 's|\./||')"
                                if [ "$dry_run" != "yes" ]; then
                                    mv --backup=t "$fileB" $duplicates_dir
                                fi
                            else
                                echo "  $(echo $fileA | sed 's|\./||')" \
                                    "is a duplicate of" \
                                    "$(echo $fileB | sed 's|\./||')"
                                if [ "$dry_run" != "yes" ]; then
                                    mv --backup=t "$fileA" $duplicates_dir
                                fi
                            fi
                        fi
                    fi
                done
            fi
        done
    fi
done

rm -r $filelist_dir

if [ "$dry_run" != "yes" ]; then
    echo "Duplicates moved to $duplicates_dir."
fi
```